# How to access php while loop variables in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I have completed a php page with my poor logic but working fine... i want to access data of that page into smarty page. Page name id dealers.php and theme page name is dealers.html

I want to access while loop data into smarty

```
$q1=mysql_query("select * from class_users where active=1 and store=1 ORDER BY rand() limit 8");

while ($ev= mysql_fetch_object($q1)){
$did = "$ev->id";
$dname = "$ev->contact_name";
$drating     = "$ev->rating";
$rating = round($drating);
$dnorating = "$ev->no_ratings";
$dphoto  = "$ev->photo";
$dc  = "$ev->company_name";
$store_banner    = "$ev->store_banner";
$durl = preg_replace('~[^A-Za-zds-]+~u', '',  strtolower($dname));
}
```

it mean i am storing data from database in variables... so i want to use this variables into smarty template file. How to assign while loop and how to get while loop variables in smarty ...?

dealer.php 
$smarty->assign(dealer_name, $dname);

dealers.html 
{$dealer_name}

It showing only one name one time. Need to get all dealers from database using above php logic. Just tell me how to assccess these variables in dealers.html

Comment: What do you mean "While loop data"? What kind of loop? I don't see any Smarty code in your question

Comment: it mean i am storing data from database in variables... so i want to use this variables into smarty template file.

How to assign while loop and how to get while loop variables in smarty ...?

dealer.php
$smarty->assign(dealer_name, $dname);

dealers.html
{$dealer_name}
It showing only one name one time. Need to get all dealers from database using above php logic.

Just tell me how to assccess these variables in dealers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to assign it into an `array` and then loop through your array

```
$data = array();
while ($ev= mysql_fetch_assoc($q1)){
    $data[] = $ev;
}
$smarty->assign('users', $data);
```

And then in your Smarty template (note, this syntax assumes Smarty 3 or later)

```
{foreach $users as $user}
    <div>{$user.contact_name} - {$user.contact_name}</div>
{/foreach}
```